# Get relative date from the NOW() function

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I try to get the relative date and time from the MySQL `NOW()` function, (like 2 seconds ago, 3 days ago, on the 31st of december...) but I have no idea how! Any ideas? Thank you so much!

Comment: There is no `NOW()` fonction in php

Comment: there is the mysql fonction ...

Comment: I'm sorry, it's in Mysql

Comment: you want to look add date_add and date_subtract ` SELECT .., NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY as yeseterday ... etc

Comment: I have a field in MySQL that is TIMESTAMP. I want to obtain on my website the relative time based on the date shown in the TIMESTAMP field.

Comment: then DATEDIFF(NOW(),YOUR_DATE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function. See example:

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `stamp_column`, NOW()) as `seconds`
FROM
    `YourTable`
```

Or use this stored function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `PassedSince`(`stamp` TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE `result` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE `seconds`, `minutes`, `hours`, `days` INT;

SET `seconds` = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `stamp`, NOW());

SET `days`    = `seconds` DIV (24 * 60 * 60);
SET `seconds` = `seconds` MOD (24 * 60 * 60);

IF `days` > 0
THEN SET `result` = CONCAT(`result`, `days`, ' Days ');
END IF;

SET `hours`   = `seconds` DIV (60 * 60);
SET `seconds` = `seconds` MOD (60 * 60);

IF `hours` > 0
THEN SET `result` = CONCAT(`result`, `hours`, ' Hours ');
END IF;

SET `minutes` = `seconds` DIV 60;
SET `seconds` = `seconds` MOD 60;

IF `minutes` > 0
THEN SET `result` = CONCAT(`result`, `minutes`, ' Minutes ');
END IF;

IF `seconds` > 0
THEN SET `result` = CONCAT(`result`, `seconds`, ' Seconds ');
END IF;

RETURN TRIM(`result`);
END
```

For query:

```
SELECT
    `PassedSince`('2013-06-19 08:00') as `result`
UNION ALL
SELECT
    `PassedSince`('2013-01-01 00:00')
```

Shows:

```
result
--------------------------------------
1 Hours 20 Minutes 55 Seconds
169 Days 9 Hours 20 Minutes 55 Seconds
```

Comment: It wont fit for 3 days ago, 1 hour ago. I'm afraid more if/else has to be done after fetching from mysql.

Comment: i don't like the back ticks ever where, but that's just me.

Comment: @AaronJiang yes. Just give me some time `:)` I'm not an AI to compute it in nanoseconds. Stored functions is the way.

Comment: something like this http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/9368/ there are a few of theses about

Comment: How do you get de TIMESTAMPDIFF?

Comment: @fred8695 its a 'built-in' function

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the time, or in your case the seconds, beforehand.

Let me illustrate what I mean, with simple example, based on a PDO-Mysql query

```
$time = '0:01:00'; // one minute

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT chat_user FROM chatters  
                        WHERE TIMEDIFF(NOW(), login_time) < TIME (?) );
```

In the above example, if you use the query, you will actually be searching for a user whose login time, is less than `$time` or `01:00:00`